# How to centre align the content of windows form application?

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I am developing a simple windows form application. But I am not able to center align the contents of the form. here are the images: [image]

Here's the code of the form:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
partial class Form1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Form1));
        this.textBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.pictureBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
        this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1)).BeginInit();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // textBox1
        // 
        this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1, 1);
        this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
        this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
        this.textBox1.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this.button1.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("button1.BackgroundImage")));
        this.button1.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Center;
        this.button1.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Highlight;
        this.button1.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 5;
        this.button1.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.HotTrack;
        this.button1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Coral;
        this.button1.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("button1.Image")));
        this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(330, 275);
        this.button1.Name = "button1";
        this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(97, 123);
        this.button1.TabIndex = 1;
        this.button1.UseMnemonic = false;
        this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
        // 
        // pictureBox1
        // 
        this.pictureBox1.Enabled = false;
        this.pictureBox1.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("pictureBox1.Image")));
        this.pictureBox1.ImageLocation = "";
        this.pictureBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(270, 27);
        this.pictureBox1.Name = "pictureBox1";
        this.pictureBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(221, 176);
        this.pictureBox1.TabIndex = 2;
        this.pictureBox1.TabStop = false;
        this.pictureBox1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.pictureBox1_Click);
        // 
        // label1
        // 
        this.label1.AutoSize = true;
        this.label1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("OCR A Extended", 14.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Italic, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(251, 226);
        this.label1.Name = "label1";
        this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(251, 20);
        this.label1.TabIndex = 3;
        this.label1.Text = "Please Touch Your Card";
        this.label1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.label1_Click);
        // 
        // label2
        // 
        this.label2.AutoSize = true;
        this.label2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        this.label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(359, 433);
        this.label2.Name = "label2";
        this.label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(35, 13);
        this.label2.TabIndex = 4;
        this.label2.Text = "label2";
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Highlight;
        this.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Stretch;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(752, 502);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.textBox1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label2);
        this.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox1);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.WindowsDefaultBounds;
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized;
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1)).EndInit();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;

    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label2;
    private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pictureBox1;
}

}
```

I tried using this,

```
  this.label1.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
```

But even that did not help.

Comment: are you trying to get all the controls on the center of your form? as in the textbox and those controls, not just text

Comment: yes, except the text box. But the property box on the right side doesn't have option for that. when i launch the form, it launches in full screen mode, in full screen mode i want everything you can see except textbox in centre of the form.

Comment: Have you tried the `TableLayoutPanel`? you can place it over your entire form by docking it, and putting each control in its own cell. then you can set column sizes and row sizes. if you create 3 columns (column 1: 50%, column 2: autosize, column 3: 50%) and put all your controls that need centered in the second column, and the textbox in the first column so it stays on the left

Comment: No, I haven't. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you try the `TableLayoutPanel`, if you add one you shall get a small 2x2 grid. If you right click and say edit rows and columns you can add a third column and the amount of rows you need. for the settings of the panel I'd suggest something along these lines:

> column1 : 50%
>
> column2 : autosize
>
> column3 : 50%

This will make it so the middle column is the minimal required size for your controls, and the remainder of the width is divided over the other 2 columns. Don't forget to dock the tableLayoutPanel to the form.

Thought I'd post it as an awnser instead of the comment I left before.

Comment: I used this. This is just perfect.

Comment: @RiteshThakur glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do is to use `TableLayoutPanel` as @maam27 commented. Another way is to use the `Anchor` property of the control. By default a control is anchored to the top-left corner of the parent form. So when form resizes, that point remains fixed. You may choose to break the left anchor. Manually center-align your components in designer. After that if your form resizes, then the relative position will remain unchanged.

Comment: I feel like that would work fine if you want to center things on just the width, but if OP would want to center it on height as well it may not be enough anymore. Also putting it on the exact center could be a bit of a hassle. I still think it's good to have multiple options on something like this.

Answer (score -1):

you take a DIV than assign align inline property for label

Comment: it is a winforms question, not web. Here we do not have divs :(